# Bipolar capacitor replacement with very different dimension

Tags: capacitor, bipolar

I need to replace a 25VNP / 10MFD bipolar capacitor (the gray one in the picture).
I have a 35VNP / 10MFD (bipolar) capacitor replacement. However it's very small compared to the 25VNP one. The gray one comes from a 1977 CRT board, and the green one is brand new. Should I care about the capacitor dimensions or it's irrelevant? [image: capacitor replacement]

Comment: Can you pull the existing one and measure it? Also check or guestimate from the circuit, the ripple current rating. If the replacement has a lower ripple current rating it may have a very short life.

Comment: can you measure that grey capacitor, (how tall, what diameter,  and what part of the circuit is it in?  vertical? horizontal?, power supply? audio?

Answer (score 1):

10 mF means 10 milli farads or 10,000 μF (micro farads). Your replacement is possibly a thousand times too small in capacitance value.

[image]

I'd also have a concern about the letters "NP" after the 25 volt rating marking. There's a possibility that it stands for "non-polarized" so, you should ensure that any replacement is suitable.

### Regards the use of "MFD"

I'd like to cite a few examples of a capacitor marked with "MFD" as representative of milli farads but I can't. Every example I've seen of a capacitor marked "MFD" has a value in μF (micro farads) so, I'm beginning to have doubts. Certainly the term mF is used in several places around the world to represent milli-farads.

So, erring on the cautious side, maybe the grey capacitor is 25 μF but it is so big because it might be non-polarized.

Comment: ooops. thank you :)

Comment: this seems unlikely,  every othjer time I've seen it  "MFD" meant "µF" not "mF"

Comment: @Jasen it's quite common in North America to use MFD to mean milli-farads.

Comment: @Andyaka, interesting, can you cite any clear examples?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Jasen

Comment: the capacitor is NOT polarized @Andyaka

Answer (score 0):

The CRT deflection circuit NP caps are usually larger to help dissipate the heat generated when used at 15.7kHz.  If you can even find cap data sheets from back in the day they won't tell you that it is about dissipating heat, but they were purpose built for the deflection application and were physically larger than other similar marked value BP/NP caps of the era.  My best guess at a usable replacement would be to use 105C or 125C high endurance/lifetime (8000hr. + rated) 2x value polarized caps with either both ++ or -- terminals series(ed) together and hope you can make it fit in the original's space